# Напоминает "голубя в детстве" или "голубя из детства"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать?

> Этот цвет напоминает мне моего голубя в детстве

или

> Этот цвет напоминает мне моего голубя из детства

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *…напоминает мне моего...*
   Я бы разделила два местоимения или убрала одно из них.
2. ...голубя в детстве...
   Голубь в детстве — это голубёнок, птенец голубя.
3. *Этот цвет напоминает... голубя...*
   Лучше написать "окрас голубя", если Вам вспомнился цвет, а не собственно голубь.
4. Если это полное предложение (не часть), то оно начинается с большой буквы и заканчивается точкой.

Мне этот цвет напоминает окрас моего голубя из детства.
Этот цвет заставил меня вспомнить голубя из моего детства.
Этот цвет напомнил моего голубя из детства.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказала так: *Этот цвет напоминает мне  голубя из моего детства.*

А еще лучше: *Этот цвет как у голубя из моего детства*. (Можно обойтись без "напоминает").

А слово "окрас" сюда не подходит для этого разговорного (нейтрального) стиля. Окрас - это термин из книги по биологии (описание вида).

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее второй вариант (только не "голубья", а "голуб**я**"). В первом варианте заметна двусмысленность: можно подумать, что речь идёт о "детстве голубя", который раньше (в своём "детстве") был этого цвета.